# Android NDK JNI call libc function

Tags: android-ndk, libc

I was wondering whether the calling of a libc function in a native function done via JNI with the Android NDK, e.g.

```
FILE* file = fopen("sdcard/hello.txt","w+");
```

is actually going directly to the actual libc function or whether there is some proxy/wrapper between the call and the native function.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected and no performance issues when I do that.

For your code, you need to add a `/` before `sdcard` though.

Getting the right path to you sdcard might be tricky:

[How can I get external SD card path for Android 4.0+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0)

Comment: how do you know that the function is called directly? I built a custom android emulator: I log in fopen.c when the function is called. When I do call it from my NDK App, nothing gets logged, on other occasions from the System, it does get logged. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21136622/883083

Comment: Directly means without going through the JVM? The NDK could have its own native implementation of `fopen`...

Comment: Thanks for your help. Well with "directly" I meant that the App uid is the one that will be found when calling getuid() in fopen(). However it seems that fopen does not really get called. I looked for other declarations of fopen but no luck. There are similar methods like fopen (e.g. qemu_fopen() in external/qemu ) but all of them end up calling fopen() of stdio.h